# How to test methods in Saga that has internal state

Tags: axon

given this saga:

```
@Saga
@Getter
@Slf4j
public class TasksForStateSaga {

    @Autowired
    transient CommandGateway commandGateway;

    @Autowired
    transient EventBus eventBus;

    @Autowired
    transient TaskService taskService;

    Map<String, TaskStatus> tasks = new HashMap<>();

    ApplicationState applicationState;

    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "id")
    public void on(ApplicationStateChangedEvent event) {
        applicationState = event.getNewState();
        log.info("Planning tasks for application {} in state {}", event.getId(), applicationState);
        taskService.getTasksByState(applicationState).stream()
                .map(task -> ScheduleTaskCommand.builder()
                        .applicationId(event.getId())
                        .taskId(IdentifierFactory.getInstance().generateIdentifier())
                        .targetState(applicationState)
                        .taskName(task.getTaskName())
                        .build())
                .peek(command -> tasks.put(command.getTaskId(), SCHEDULED))
                .forEach(command -> commandGateway.send(command));
    }

    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "applicationId")
    public void on(TaskFinishedEvent event) {
        tasks.replace(event.getTaskId(), FINISHED);
        long notFinished = getUnfinishedCount();

        log.info("Task {} has just finished, ready {} of {}", event.getTaskName(), tasks.size() - notFinished, tasks.size());

        if (notFinished == 0) {
            log.info("All tasks for application {}.{} finished, ending this saga", event.getApplicationId(), applicationState);
            eventBus.publish(GenericEventMessage.asEventMessage(
                    TaskForStateDoneEvent.builder()
                            .applicationId(event.getApplicationId())
                            .state(applicationState)
                            .build()
            ));
            SagaLifecycle.end();
        }
    }

    private long getUnfinishedCount() {
        return tasks.values().stream()
                .filter(state -> !FINISHED.equals(state))
                .count();
    }
}
```

And have this test (Spock) testing the first method:

```
class TasksForStateSagaTest extends Specification {

SagaTestFixture sagaFixture

def setup() {
    sagaFixture = new SagaTestFixture<>(TasksForStateSaga)
}

def 'should schedule task for the application state'() {
    given:
    def applicationId = '1'
    def taskService = Mock(TaskService)
    def tasks = [
            ApplicationStateAwareTaskDefinition.builder().taskName('task1').build(),
            ApplicationStateAwareTaskDefinition.builder().taskName('task2').build(),
    ]
    sagaFixture.registerResource(taskService)
    sagaFixture.givenAggregate(applicationId)

    when:
    sagaFixture
            .whenPublishingA(new ApplicationStateChangedEvent(id: applicationId, newState: ApplicationState.NEW))
            .expectActiveSagas(1)
            .expectDispatchedCommandsMatching(payloadsMatching(
            exactSequenceOf(
                    equalTo(new ScheduleTaskCommand(applicationId: applicationId, targetState: ApplicationState.NEW, taskName: 'task1'),
                            new IgnoreField(ScheduleTaskCommand, 'taskId')),
                    equalTo(new ScheduleTaskCommand(applicationId: applicationId, targetState: ApplicationState.NEW, taskName: 'task2'),
                            new IgnoreField(ScheduleTaskCommand, 'taskId')),
                    andNoMore()
            )
    ))

    then:
    1 * taskService.getTasksByState(ApplicationState.NEW) >> tasks

}
```

}

But I actually have no clue how to test the second method, which uses the Saga's internal state.

Could anyone advice me how to set the internal saga's state via SagaTestFixture?
Or even more, is this the good way how to implement such saga or I have there some conceptual issues preventing me to test the end saga method easily?

the @StartSaga method sets the internal state - generates taskId and sets it into map
the @EndSaga method reads the map and checks if all tasks are done prior it sends TaskForStateDoneEvent event

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this by defining callback for the saga fixture. This callbacks catches all the commands of the desired type and stores the ids temporally

```
def 'saga should end when all scheduled tasks finished'() {
    given:
    def applicationId = '1'
    def taskService = Mock(TaskService)
    def tasks = [
            ApplicationStateAwareTaskDefinition.builder().taskName('task1').build(),
            ApplicationStateAwareTaskDefinition.builder().taskName('task2').build(),
    ]
    def scheduleTaskCommands = []

    sagaFixture.registerResource(taskService)
    sagaFixture.setCallbackBehavior(new CallbackBehavior() {
        @Override
        Object handle(Object commandPayload, MetaData commandMetaData) {
            if (commandPayload instanceof ScheduleTaskCommand) {
                // catch the issued commands to get the new task ids
                scheduleTaskCommands << commandPayload
            }

            commandPayload
        }
    })

    when:
    sagaFixture
            .givenAggregate(applicationId)
            .published(new ApplicationStateChangedEvent(
            applicationId: applicationId,
            newState: ApplicationState.NEW
    ))
    // publish event to finish first task (first from two)
    sagaFixture.givenAPublished(new TaskFinishedEvent(
            taskName: 'someTaskName',
            applicationId: applicationId,
            taskId: scheduleTaskCommands[0].taskId,
            taskResult: new TaskResult(
                    status: TaskResultStatus.SUCCEED,
                    message: 'ok'
            )))

    // verify the behaviour after second task finished
    sagaFixture
            .whenPublishingA(new TaskFinishedEvent(
            taskName: 'someTaskName',
            applicationId: applicationId,
            taskId: scheduleTaskCommands[1].taskId,
            taskResult: new TaskResult(
                    status: TaskResultStatus.SUCCEED,
                    message: 'ok'
            )))
            .expectActiveSagas(0)
            .expectPublishedEvents(new TasksForStateFinishedEvent(
            applicationId: applicationId,
            state: ApplicationState.NEW
    ))

    then:
    1 * taskService.getTasksByState(ApplicationState.NEW) >> tasks
}
```